# How to Output Dynamic Values to Postman Collection Runner

Tags: testing, automated-tests, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to write tests for the Postman Collection Runner and would like more visual feedback from the runner.

I know I can look at responses in the log, but it would be nice to inject variables into the GUI.

I tried the following, but all that was returned to the GUI was the string 'Qty returned is number'.

```
pm.test('Qty returned is number' + ' ' + pm.response.json().qty, pm.response.json().qty, () => {
  pm.expect(typeof parseInt(pm.response.json().qty)).to.be.not.equal('NaN');
});
```

[image]

Is it possible to return these values to the runner?

Comment: You have repeated the same reference in the test name so maybe it's not really understanding what you want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you answered my question below. The template literal syntax was what I was looking for... Thanks!!

Comment: You have `pm.response.json().qty` twice in the test name above, not sure why that was? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, like the way you tried but perhaps your reference isn't quite right?

```
pm.test(`UserId Number: ${pm.response.json()[0].userId} - My Test`, () => {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200)
})
```

Using this basic `test` example on a request to the http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=1 endpoint.

This the response data from the endpoint:

[image: Response]

Populating name on the Test:

[image: Test Name]